# How to read xml on the basis of name attribute and get value

Tags: c#, xml

```
<root>
    <Message type="sms">
        <Details locale="en" message-type="User.ResetPassword" />
        <Context>
            <Parameter name="Time" value=" 16:03:31" />
            <Parameter name="pswr" value="00" />
            <Parameter name="Date" value="18/12/2014" />
        </Context>
        <Receiver>+923328749199</Receiver>
    </Message>
</root>
```

How can I read this file? For example, I want to get the value of time, password and date, and also receiver tag value.

Comment: can u please simply code to read this file?

Comment: I done. @Quadeer Hussain,

Answer (score 0):

your class will be like this.

```
   /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM,
DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, 
ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

namespace AutoGeneratedCode
{

   /// 
   [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34234")]
   [System.SerializableAttribute()]
   [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
   [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
   public partial class root
   {
      private rootMessage messageField;
      /// 
      public rootMessage Message
      {
         get
         {
            return this.messageField;
         }
         set
         {
            this.messageField = value;
         }
      }
   }
   /// 
   [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34234")]
   [System.SerializableAttribute()]
   [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
   [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
   public partial class rootMessage
   {
      private rootMessageDetails detailsField;
      private rootMessageParameter[] contextField;
      private decimal receiverField;
      private string typeField;
      /// 
      public rootMessageDetails Details
      {
         get
         {
            return this.detailsField;
         }
         set
         {
            this.detailsField = value;
         }
      }
      /// 
      [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Parameter", IsNullable=false)]
      public rootMessageParameter[] Context
      {
         get
         {
            return this.contextField;
         }
         set
         {
            this.contextField = value;
         }
      }
      /// 
      public decimal Receiver
      {
         get
         {
            return this.receiverField;
         }
         set
         {
            this.receiverField = value;
         }
      }
      /// 
      [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
      public string type
      {
         get
         {
            return this.typeField;
         }
         set
         {
            this.typeField = value;
         }
      }
   }
   /// 
   [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34234")]
   [System.SerializableAttribute()]
   [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
   [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
   public partial class rootMessageDetails
   {
      private string localeField;
      private string messagetypeField;
      /// 
      [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
      public string locale
      {
         get
         {
            return this.localeField;
         }
         set
         {
            this.localeField = value;
         }
      }
      /// 
      [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("message-type")]
      public string messagetype
      {
         get
         {
            return this.messagetypeField;
         }
         set
         {
            this.messagetypeField = value;
         }
      }
   }
   /// 
   [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34234")]
   [System.SerializableAttribute()]
   [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
   [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
   public partial class rootMessageParameter
   {
      private string nameField;
      private System.DateTime valueField;
      private bool valueFieldSpecified;
      /// 
      [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
      public string name
      {
         get
         {
            return this.nameField;
         }
         set
         {
            this.nameField = value;
         }
      }
      /// 
      [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
      public System.DateTime value
      {
         get
         {
            return this.valueField;
         }
         set
         {
            this.valueField = value;
         }
      }
      /// 
      [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
      public bool valueSpecified
      {
         get
         {
            return this.valueFieldSpecified;
         }
         set
         {
            this.valueFieldSpecified = value;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

after your code deserialization

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(root));

using (var file = File.OpenText("sample.xml"))
{
    root data = (root)serializer.Deserialize(file);

    // ... 
}
```

You can use data to reach all members by  root object.

Answer (score 0):

Hope Helps..........

```
Dim Xdoc As XDocument
    Xdoc = XDocument.Parse(pstrXmlInput)
    Dim Tktno = From Attbvalue In Xdoc.Descendants("Context").Elements("Parameter").Attributes("value")
                Select Attbvalue.Value
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks but it giving me error data at the root level is invalid

Comment: @QadeerHussain In which case your XML is invalid... which means it doesn't match the XML you've put in the question.

Comment: r y trying same xml file and try to debug at xdoc and see what xml u get

Comment: XDocument Xdoc = XDocument.Parse("C:\\Users\\qadeer.hussain\\Desktop\\gw-msg-2.xml");
             var y = from nm in Xdoc.Descendants("Context").Elements("Parameter").Attributes("value") select nm.Value;
             Response.Write(y.Count());

Comment: i am trying to parse same xml my code is above posted

Comment: @QadeerHussain You're not, you're trying to parse a file path.  If you want to load from a file, you need `XDocument.Load`.

Comment: **XDocument.Parse** is used to prase string only.

Comment: ok now i change to load code is

Comment: XDocument Xdoc= XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\qadeer.hussain\\Desktop\\gw-msg-2.xml");
             var y = from nm in Xdoc.Descendants("Context").Elements("Parameter").Attributes("Time") select nm.Value;
             Response.Write(y);

Comment: now this message is coming    System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute,System.String]

Comment: why r u using attribute time which doesnt exist in Xdoc.Descendants("Context").Elements("Parameter"). **Attributes("Time")**

Comment: sorry but if i use value same message coming

Comment: I uploaded snapshot verify its working on my side

Answer (score 0):

Use [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Here is my solution:

If your xml come from a URL use XDocument.Load(/*URL*/)

```
var xml = "<root><Message type='sms'><Details locale='en' message-type='User.ResetPassword' /><Context><Parameter name='Time' value=' 16:03:31' /><Parameter name='pswr' value='00' /><Parameter name='Date' value='18/12/2014' /></Context><Receiver>+923328749199</Receiver></Message></root>";
var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var messages = document.Root.Elements();
foreach (var message in messages)
{
    var context = message.Element("Context");
    var parameters = context.Elements("Parameter");
    foreach (var parameter in parameters)
    {
        var name = parameter.Attribute("name").Value;
        var value = parameter.Attribute("value").Value;

        Console.WriteLine ("Parameter {0} with value of {1}", name, value);
    }

    Console.WriteLine ("Receiver {0}", message.Element("Receiver").Value);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Parameter Time with value of  16:03:31
Parameter pswr with value of 00
Parameter Date with value of 18/12/2014
Receiver +923328749199
```